# Copying files from a folder to new ones from a list that does not exactly match the file names

Tags: automation, windows-scripting, office-automation

I've got a tough one here and I couldn't find help anywhere else.

I've got a few lists of part numbers and I need to copy the technical drawing files for these part numbers to specific folders.

The main issue is that although the file names match the list, except for the drawing version (there is always `_001` or `_002`, etc after the part number and before the extension), it's not an exact match.

So, basically, I have to copy the files from an Excel list but I have to instruct whatever method/software I use to consider the latest version of the drawings based on the suffix on the file name. What would be the best (and easiest) method to do it?

I haven't got access to any programming tools in my work computer outside of Windows/Office and I'm not sure using VBA would be the answer.

Can anyone help me with the task?

Answer (score 0):

So, after a lot of digging I managed to find a solution. I am aware it could have all been done in coding, but I'm still learning and it could help someone with the same problem
1. I opened CMD, went to the folder where the files were and typed `dir /b>list.txt`. This generated a txt list with all the files within the folder.
2. I open the txt file in Excel and adjusted it so that I had one file name per cell.
3. On the original part number list I added a column to the right and added an "X" to it just for the vlookup.
4. I used a vlookup on the file list against the parts list to see which files I would require.
5. I removed all file names from the list that weren't on the parts list.
6. I sorted the file names alphabetically.
7. I extracted the part number from the file name to a separate cell (A3) `=left(A1,14)`.
8. Did `=A3=A4`. Whatever returned "TRUE" was deleted (if the part number in one line was equal the one on the line below, it meant it was the same drawing in an older version).
9. Used the code below on Excel (VBA) to copy the files from the original folder to a new folder based on the list I put together.

```
Sub copyfiles()
Dim xRg As Range, xCell As Range
Dim xSFileDlg As FileDialog, xDFileDlg As FileDialog
Dim xSPathStr As Variant, xDPathStr As Variant
Dim xVal As String
On Error Resume Next
Set xRg = Application.InputBox("Click on the column with the file names:", "File copier", ActiveWindow.RangeSelection.Address, , , , , 8)
If xRg Is Nothing Then Exit Sub
Set xSFileDlg = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFolderPicker)
xSFileDlg.Title = "Folder to copy from:"
If xSFileDlg.Show <> -1 Then Exit Sub
xSPathStr = xSFileDlg.SelectedItems.Item(1) & "\"
Set xDFileDlg = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFolderPicker)
xDFileDlg.Title = "Folder to copy to:"
If xDFileDlg.Show <> -1 Then Exit Sub
xDPathStr = xDFileDlg.SelectedItems.Item(1) & "\"
For Each xCell In xRg
    xVal = xCell.Value
    If TypeName(xVal) = "String" And xVal <> "" Then
        FileCopy xSPathStr & xVal, xDPathStr & xVal
    End If
Next
```

End Sub